# How to get the current row of list of strings with map()

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
      {words.map((word: string, index) => (
        <Span key={index}>
          <Span>
            {word}
          </Span>
        </Span>
      ))}
```

This is giving me number of lines of different words in my browser. What I would like to do is shown in the picture:
[image]

If there are more then three rows of words I want to show only first three rows of words and add "..." as a sign that there are more words in the list that are not shown.
Does anyone have idea how I can do that? How to find on which row of words I am?

Comment: How you identifying number of rows?

Comment: It is allowed to have only three rows, and right now using map() I can not be sure at what row of words I am

Comment: How are you storing values in `words`?

Comment: words is an array of strings - one dimensional array of strings

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many characters fit per line, you could do a calculation based off of that. For clarification, though: do you just want to show an ellipsis at the end, or is that supposed to be a clickable element to expand the container to show the entire list? If it's the more basic part, you could do it all via JS or use CSS pseudo-content.

Example JS:

```
const container = document.querySelector('.words-list'); // whatever contains the list of words
const wordsStr = words.join(', ');
const lineChars = 20;
const linesToShow = 3;
if (wordsStr.length > lineChars * linesToShow) {
    let wordsSub = wordsStr.substr(0, lineChars * linesToShow - 3) + '&hellip;';
    container.innerText = wordsSub;
}
```

For the CSS portion, once you've added a class via JS, you can use `text-overflow: ellipsis` or `::after { content: '\2026' }`.